# Developer over Qps

Tags: google-app-engine

I use the free app engine but it keeps returning the following error 9 times out of 10:

Object {0: "Developer Over Qps"}

As I understanding, there is no limitation on the Qps, even with the free plan.

Any way, even querying my app every 1-2s is too much apparently.

Any idea what could be going on?

---

### AFTER COMMENT EDITS

I use my google engine app to query a third party api:

client -> google app engine -> third party API

1- the client does an AJAX request to the app engine server.

2- the server is a very simple php script which queries a 3rd party API and returns a JSON to the client.

to query the 3rd party API from the PHP app engine, I use 'file_get_contents'

```
file_get_contents('http://api.sportsdatallc.org/soccer-t2/eu/matche...');
```

We do **2** queries to the 3rd party API in a short amount of time.

It appears that the PHP google app engine returns 'Developer Over Qps' if we try to query the app engine more than 1 time very 2-3s.

Does it sound reasonable for the free quota? I sounds very few to me, even for the free quota.

I'm wondering if the bottleneck is:

1- the 2 'fast' queries to the 3rd party API from the app engine php?
2- the 'slow' AJAX query from my client to the app engine

(This is the first time I use the app engine and I am trying to understand it...)

Comment: Is this within a transaction? with ancestor queries or without? What exactly are you talking by "query"... techincally urlFetch has a "qps" you can go over as well.... this error in itself doesn't mean much.  And yes there are limits for QPS, even in free applications

Comment: Thanks, please see the edits to see if it makes more sense now...

Comment: Just to make sure - are you sure it's the App Engine that's returning the error and not the third party API?

Comment: Inestigating right now. The problem appears to be the 2 queries between the app engine and the 3rd party api. When I run it locally, everything was working fine. After deployment this error started to appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`Object {0: "Developer Over Qps"}`**

This doesn't seem like something GAE returns. Querying an app every 1-2 seconds is also not much at all, even on free tire.

The issue is probably with the 3rd party API not being able to handle (or simply limiting) the number of requests you are sending.

If this is true, the simplest solution would be to cache the results, unless of-course you are getting new data every single request in which case you would have to contact the 3rd party API provider.

Comment: I guess I didn't notice before (while developping locally) because the PHP runs faster on the GAE than on my machine...